# Record short audio file using WebRTC

Tags: audio, compression, webrtc, recording

In online social learning app, we want participants to be able to record short audio clips to share with others. Typically a recording will be a spoken word or a single sentence.

I've been looking at WebRTC. I understand how to create and share an audio stream. However, we want the participant to be able to start the recording manually, and to stop it when it's complete (or after 15 seconds if that is sooner). Ideally, we want to compress the resulting file to save bandwidth, and upload it to a database.

Can anyone recommend any tutorials on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [RecordRTC](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC) help you. https://webrtc-experiment.appspot.com/RecordRTC/

**Try this demo:**

https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/AudioVideoRecorder

In the demo; `MediaRecorder API` is used to record audio streams. It is exactly what you want; however current support is Firefox Nightly (only).

Chrome team also [started discussing](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/2l_G_apqk30) possible scenarios; and impacts. They'll implement `MediaRecorder API` soon.

Comment: Hi Muaz! Thanks for the link. I've also found this: [link](http://www.sajithmr.me/jrecorder-jquery)

Comment: Having just tried the RecordRTC on chrome 29 on ubuntu, it doesn't seem to work, as in, everything seems to go well, except the resulting file is silent. According to http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=252279, it looks like this only works in OSX. Is that right?

Comment: It works on windows too (except XP)...read list of possible failures here: https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC#possible-issuesfailures

Comment: Is there no Linux support at all?